# how to find which button clicks when we goto next activity in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have two buttons in first activity, and I want to go next activity when button clicks.

Button names are, for example, `Button1` and `Button2`

```
//assume both button text same as id

Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

//button1 on click event
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Second.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

//button2 on click event

    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Second.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

Both click events go to same activity by using `Intents`.

How can we find which button was clicked when it comes to the second activity(in `getIntent()` or else)?

Comment: You need to use something along the lines of a Handler, to pass and receive a string with "button1" or "button2".

Answer (score 3):

Within the `Intent` that takes you to the next `Activity`, you can do the following

```
intent.putExtra("buttonId", button1.getId());
```

In your new `Activity`,

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int id = intent.getIntExtra("buttonId", -1);
if(id == -1){
    Log.e("test_tag", "Error. Unknown button ID");
} else {
    Log.d("test_tag", "You clicked button " + id);
}
```

Or

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int id = intent.getIntExtra("buttonId", -1);
if(id == R.id.button1){
    Log.d("test_tag", "Button 1 clicked.");
} else {
    Log.d("test_tag", "You clicked something else.");
}
```

Comment: ok then how we compare the id in if else statement?

strId = value of that buttonID
if(strId == "??"){
}

which value i need to compare in this ?? mark

Comment: I recommend at least starting with the first one since it checks for an error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got solution like bellow.

#### In first screen :

```
//assume both button text same as id

Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

//button1 on click event
button1.OnClick(){
intent.putExtra("Action",button1.getText().toString());
}

//button2 on click event
button2.OnClick(){
intent.putExtra("Action",button2.getText().toString());
}
```

#### In second screen :

```
Intent resultintent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle=resultintent.getExtras();
final String btnAction=bundle.getString("Action");

if(btnAction.equals("button1")){
    //action from button 1
}else{
    //action from button 2
}
```

Comment: This is, effectively, the answer that I gave you.